# create column in datatable depending on it's values

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation, shift

I have got single column in data table

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(con=c(1:5))
```

My result is a data table with new column x calculated as follows: first value should be first value of con(here:1), next(second) value should be calculated by muliplication second value of con times first value of x. Third value of x is a result of multiplcation third value of con times second value of x and so on. Result:

```
 DT <- data.table(con=c(1:5), x = c(1,2,6,24,120))
```

I tried use shifts but it did non helped, below some lines of my code:

```
DT <- data.table(con=c(1:5))
DT[, x := shift(con,1, type = "lead")]
DT[, x := shift(x, 1)]
DT[, x := con * x]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `cumprod`

```
DT[,x:=cumprod(con)]
DT
   con   x
1:   1   1
2:   2   2
3:   3   6
4:   4  24
5:   5 120
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `accumulate` function from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package.

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

DT <- data.table(con=c(1:5))
DT[, x := accumulate(con, `*`)][]
#    con   x
# 1:   1   1
# 2:   2   2
# 3:   3   6
# 4:   4  24
# 5:   5 120
```

Or the `Reduce` function from the base R.

```
DT <- data.table(con=c(1:5))
DT[, x:= Reduce(`*`, con, accumulate = TRUE)][]
#    con   x
# 1:   1   1
# 2:   2   2
# 3:   3   6
# 4:   4  24
# 5:   5 120
```